# Translating a relational data structure to nosql?

Tags: mongodb, relational-database, nosql

I'm looking for best practices on converting relational data structures to NoSQL. I found this gem, [Relational to NoSQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849571/relational-to-nosql-database), which had a lot of great information, but I'm interested in industry standards, lexicon, and more in-depth analysis and examples.

Notice, I'm not concerned with actual data migration at this point. Only best practices associated with flattening a relational database.

Can anyone recommend any *articles, books, textbooks*, etc that could help? I need more information on how to transition a deeply relational Oracle database to Mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an upcoming webinar from Mongodb

https://www.mongodb.com/webinar/transitioning-from-sql-to-mongodb